# PowerShell show array item one at a time

Tags: arrays, powershell, richtextbox

I have an array and want to display each item one at a time. Each item should also be shown at different times intervals. I think I should use Start-Sleep -s 5. 
Here is my code so far.

```
function GenerateForm {

$a=
"Downloading Files", 
"Setting up VPN Connection", 
"Getting computer information", 
"Install Complete", 
"Cluster Flux Technologies", 
"You are Free to close this application" 



#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") 
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") 
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$richTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$pictureBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
$btn1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------
#Provide Custom Code for events specified in PrimalForms.
$btn1_OnClick= {
        $richTextBox1.Text = $a | Out-String
    }
    #----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,212,208,200)
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 658
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 1072
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$form1.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon('C:\Users\502706436\Desktop\tight vnc\cluster.ico')
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.Text = "Cluster Flux Technologies: VNC Installer"

$richTextBox1.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255,255)
$richTextBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$richTextBox1.Enabled = $False
$richTextBox1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,0,3,0)
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 566
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 570
$richTextBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 39
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 348
$richTextBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$richTextBox1.TabIndex = 2
$richTextBox1.Text = ""

$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox1)

$pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\Users\502706436\Desktop\tight vnc\cluster2 logo.png')
$pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = 2
$pictureBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0



$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 41
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 35
$pictureBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 454
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 949
$pictureBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$pictureBox1.TabIndex = 1
$pictureBox1.TabStop = $False

$form1.Controls.Add($pictureBox1)


$btn1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$btn1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",12,0,3,0)

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 71
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 570
$btn1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$btn1.Name = "btn1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 39
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 292
$btn1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$btn1.TabIndex = 0
$btn1.TabStop = $False
$btn1.Text = "Click to install connection"
$btn1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$btn1.add_Click($btn1_OnClick)

$form1.Controls.Add($btn1)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState

#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()

}   #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

If anyone knows or has advice on how to achieve this I would appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: That's a crudload of code and a brief description of what you want to accomplish but what part of it doesn't work? Is the variable $a the array you speak of?

Comment: Sorry, The code above dose work however I am trying to display each line in the array just one at a time in richtextbox1. A timed event would probably be the easiest way to accomplish this. When I run this code the array items are all displayed at once which is to be expected.

Comment: But why? Do you actually know there's 5 seconds between each step? It all seems so backwards to me. I don't quite get the point, but then again, perhaps I'm heavily biased towards silent installs. "You are free to close this window" just might bug me the most. I'm all for informing the end user what's going on with their computer but a simple balloon tip or such, informing the user the software install is all done and ready to use, is something I'd prefer personally.

Answer (score 0):

For updating the text ,you can use :

```
$btn1_OnClick= {
      $a | %{  $richTextBox1.Text = $_ | Out-String;Start-Sleep -s 5}
    }
```

but the above simplistic approach will freeze ui while the above block is running.you can try the below runspace approach ,which will ensure that ui is responsive during the update:

```
$btn1_OnClick= {

$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()

$PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()

$PowerShell.runspace = $Runspace

$Runspace.Open()

[void]$PowerShell.AddScript({
param($richTextBox1)

$a=
"Downloading Files", 
"Setting up VPN Connection", 
"Getting computer information", 
"Install Complete", 
"Cluster Flux Technologies", 
"You are Free to close this application" 

 $a | %{  $richTextBox1.Text = $_ | Out-String;Start-Sleep -s 5;}

}).addargument($richTextBox1)

$AsyncObject = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()

    }
```